# MediaWiki 1.16.0 - In phpmyadmin select the current articles

Tags: mysql, sql, mediawiki

I'm trying to get all articles that are the current/latest articles in Mediawiki 1.16.0. I need to do this in phpMyadmin and make a dump from those results.

my SQL:

```
SELECT 
  page.page_title, page.page_latest
  , revision.rev_id, revision.rev_text_id
  , text.old_id, text.old_text 
FROM page, revision, text 
WHERE rev_id = page_latest AND rev_text_id = old_id
```

I get the image names also but not a problem. I feel that this SQL above is not getting the latest version of the articles.

If there is a way to not show image names and redirects in the results it would also help.

Answer (score 2):

First of all please don't use that ugly implicit join syntax. It's confusing and error-prone.

Change it to this:

```
SELECT 
  page.page_title, page.page_latest
  , revision.rev_id, revision.rev_text_id
  , text.old_id, text.old_text 
FROM page
INNER JOIN revision ON (rev_id = page_latest)
INNER JOIN text ON (rev_text_id = old_id)
```

Now you can see why: it's getting **all** pages. There is no `where` clause, there are just `join` clauses.

This is the DB layout: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/MediaWiki_database_schema_1-17_%28r82044%29.png

And here are the description of the fields in the various tables:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout

**Revised query**

```
SELECT 
  p.page_title, p.page_latest
  , MAX(revision.rev_id) as rev_id, revision.rev_text_id
  , text.old_id, text.old_text 
FROM page p
INNER JOIN revision r ON (r.rev_id = p.page_latest)
INNER JOIN `text` t ON (r.rev_text_id = t.old_id)
WHERE p.page_is_redirect = 0 AND p.page_namespace <> 6  /*NS_IMAGE = 6*/
GROUP BY p.page_latest 
ORDER BY p.page_title
```

This filters out the redirects and excludes the pages where `namespace = ns_image`.

I'm not 100% sure though 'cause I don't have MediaWiki to test.

Comment: mysql complains about using full table names after you've defined an alias (i.e. page.page_title should be p.page_title).  Also page.namespace doesn't exist, should be page.page_namespace.  Otherwise, nice query.  +1